# Why am i getting a Python Discord Bot Exception Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

im working on a discord bot and i have the following code :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "im not showing that"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

inviteLink = "https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=637070452686323732&permissions=8&scope=bot"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Locked And Loaded Mr. Ironkey")

@client.command()
async def ping():
    await client.say("pong")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

(i masked the token i dont want my bot taken over lol. yes the token works fine)

i keep getting these errors when i do a command in discord, so far ive had everything working including the bot logging my messages but now its gone completely wack. any ideas on why its not working?

[image: errors]

Comment: Please copy and paste from error messages, formatting them as code, rather than taking a screenshot. Anyway: the first step to understanding Python exception tracebacks is to read them, starting from the bottom up. `discord.errors.ClientException` tells you that there was a problem detected by the discord library, to do with the client. The rest of the line tells you that a callback (the code you wrote) is missing a parameter (because it wants to pass an argument), and tells you the name of the function that has the problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was running this in a VM and it wouldn't let me copy and paste out of it or copy from the cmd window

Comment: but thanks alot that helps me alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states at the bottom of the stack trace, you need a ctx parameter (context) to respond from the function.

```
@client.command(name='ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
```

Or

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.say('pong')
```